# How to get excel to insert a new image with Applescript?

Tags: excel, automation, applescript, ms-office, ui-automation

I have the following Applescript:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active workbook
        make new picture at end with properties {save with document:true, file name:"/Users/yuval/Pictures/foobar.jpg"}
    end tell
end tell
```

According to several sources, this *should* work.

However, every time I run the script I get the message

> Microsoft Excel got an error: Can’t make class picture.

In the description, I see the error

> error "Microsoft Excel got an error: Can’t make class picture." number
>   -2710 from picture to class

After two hours of searching, I have absolutely no clue what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Details:
*Running Microsoft Excel 2011 on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, though the caveat here is that I am working in Excel 2008, but Applescript implementations don't change substantially without fanfare:

First, make sure you are using the proper file path format. Applescript historically works with HFS paths, not POSIX

```
set theFilePath to "Macintosh HD:Users:UserName:Path:To:File.pic" --choose file
```

Second, make sure you are acting on the appropriate object. I was able to make this work with `active sheet` because `active workbook` wasn't a property in the Dictionary:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet
        make new picture at end with properties {file name:theFilePath}
    end tell
end tell
```

The above code combined worked for me.

Comment: Changing the POSIX path to an HFS path solved my problem. Again, thank you so so much!